# Calling a Function with NULL as Parameter

Tags: swift

I am trying to load an image with the following Code, but I have no clue how to do this in Swift.

The [CGImage Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImage/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider) says, that I should pass NULL as parameter, but since NULL is not part of the Swift-Language this is not possible. Do I have to use UnsafePointer and if so, how?

```
var img = CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider(CGDataProviderCreateWithFilename("/Resources/image.png"),**?**, true,kCGRenderingIntentDefault)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to pass `nil` for a null value.