# Checking IP Address Reachability using SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, ip-address, reachability

I'm trying to check if a Host is available in Swift, I am using Apple's Reachability, but I can't get it to work giving it an IP Address and Port, I think my problem is that this requires a struct for the address or something, can somebody please explain / lead me into the right way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25623272/working-with-c-structs-in-swift.

Answer (score 1):

for a drop in solution in Swift, you might want to take a look here:

https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift

There are a couple of unsolved issues to (see README), but apart from that it works pretty well.

Comment: Hi! Does this works to check for reachability on a specific host address/name? If so, can you please provide an example? I've read the documentation and looked into the example, but couldn't find any way to do this. Thanks!