# How do I check if a remote host has a server running on a specific port in pure Swift?

Tags: swift, sockets, swift2, reachability

I'd like to write a function that checks whether a *hostname* is reachable on a specific *port*. So, something like:

```
func isReachable(hostname: String, port: Int, completion: (Bool) -> ()) {
    // …
}
```

or, if possible:

```
func isReachable(hostname: String, port: Int) -> Bool {
    // …
}
```

---

I've tried extending a [swift implementation](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift) of [Apple's `Reachability` utility](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) with help from this [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25623272/how-to-use-scnetworkreachability-in-swift/25623647#25623647) to come up with the following:

```
public class func reachabilityForHostname(hostname: String, port: Int) -> Reachability? {

    var address = sockaddr_in()
    address.sin_len = UInt8(sizeofValue(address))
    address.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)
    address.sin_addr = in_addr(string: hostname)
    address.sin_port = UInt16(9000).bigEndian

    let ref = withUnsafePointer(&address) {
        SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, UnsafePointer($0))
    }

    return Reachability(reachabilityRef: ref)
}
```

The problem is that the reachability object I'm creating here always displays as *reachable* (as long as my network is connected)—so it essentially doesn't actually check that the specific hostname/port is *running* (I'm trying to see if a server is running on http://localhost:9000).

I've read that `Reachability` might not actually be the way to go—as it only checks if an outward connection could be made to the specified host (not guaranteeing that the host is actually online).

---

Having said all that, my question is simply—**what are my options if I would like to check if a specific host (say localhost) has a server running on a specific port?**

Comment: Why not use something like [SwiftSocket](https://github.com/swiftsocket/SwiftSocket) with an appropriate timeout? You'll get a msg back either good or bad and you can close the socket and then do what your app need to do for either is avail or not.

Comment: Ah man, that was exactly what I was after. Please answer this question with your comment so I can mark it as correct :)