# Binary operator '&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'SCNetworkReachabilityFlags' and 'Int'

Tags: ios, swift, network-programming, swift2

I am getting this error when try to check for internet connectivity in my app.

I use Xcode 7.1.1 Swift 2.0

The code block is as follows

```
public class Reach {

class func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool {

    var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in(sin_len: 0, sin_family: 0, sin_port: 0, sin_addr: in_addr(s_addr: 0), sin_zero: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
    zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(sizeofValue(zeroAddress))
    zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

    let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(&zeroAddress, {
        SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, UnsafePointer($0))//.takeRetainedValue()
    })

    var flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = []
    if SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags( defaultRouteReachability!, &flags) == false {
        return false
    }

    //The following two lines shows the error
    let isReachable = (flags  & (kSCNetworkFlagsReachable)) != 0
    let needsConnection = (flags  & (kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired)) != 0

    return isReachable && !needsConnection
}

}
```

I tried casting the flag to Int and the NetworkFlag to UInt32 and vice versa but still it shows warnings and gets error while executing. I tried the following

```
(flags  & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsReachable))
(Int(flags)  & (kSCNetworkFlagsReachable))
(flags  & (kSCNetworkFlagsReachable) as! UInt32)
(flags as! Int  & (kSCNetworkFlagsReachable))
```

But nothing worked. Can anyone solve it

Content of SCNetworkReachabilityFlags

```
public struct SCNetworkReachabilityFlags : OptionSetType {
public init(rawValue: UInt32)

public static var TransientConnection: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags { get }
public static var Reachable: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags { get }
public static var ConnectionRequired: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags { get }
public static var ConnectionOnTraffic: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags { get }
public static var InterventionRequired: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags { get }
public static var ConnectionOnDemand: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags { get } // __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_6,__IPHONE_3_0)
public static var IsLocalAddress: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags { get }
public static var IsDirect: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags { get }

public static var IsWWAN: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags { get }
// TARGET_OS_IPHONE

public static var ConnectionAutomatic: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags { get }
```

}

Comment: What does this have to do with c++ ?

Comment: if you change `var flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = []` to `var flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = 0` does that help?

Comment: @Fonix No that throws an error.In swift2.0 to set a nil value we must use [] instead of nil .

Comment: then the variable is an array and you cant do a bitwise operation on it, so you will probably have to check if the array contains `kSCNetworkFlagsReachable` etc

Comment: @JonathanPotter sorry that tag was a auto tag suggest .But i thought that Swift is a decendant of C. so the same concepts can be in c++ too thats why i added that suggested tag too.

Comment: @Fonix See edited. Any suggestions on how to change my code?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/25623647/1187415 for a version of that function that compiles with Swift 2/Xcode 7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try just go

```
let isReachable = flags.contains(SCNetworkReachabilityFlags.Reachable)
let needsConnection = flags.contains(SCNetworkReachabilityFlags.ConnectionRequired)
```

the [OptionSetType](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_OptionSetType_Protocol/) has a convenience method for contains, so hopefully that will check if the flag is set

Comment: That works great. No errors and shows perfect answer