# Swift 3 UnsafePointer($0) no longer compile in Xcode 8 beta 6

Tags: swift3, unsafe-pointers, xcode8-beta6

My code snipet as follows …:

```
    let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(to: &zeroAddress) {
        SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, UnsafePointer($0))
    }
```

… does no longer compile with the following error which I don't understand:

```
"'init' is unavailable: use 'withMemoryRebound(to:capacity:_)' to temporarily view memory as another layout-compatible type."
```

What to do to fix it?

Comment: Note that http://stackoverflow.com/a/25623647/1187415 has been updated for the current Swift 3.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

From the Release Notes of Xcode 8 beta 6:

> - An `Unsafe[Mutable]RawPointer` type has been introduced, replacing `Unsafe[Mutable]Pointer<Void>`. Conversion from `UnsafePointer<T>` to
>     `UnsafePointer<U>` has been disallowed. `Unsafe[Mutable]RawPointer`
>     provides an API for untyped memory access, and an API for binding
>     memory to a type. Binding memory allows for safe conversion between
>     pointer types. See `bindMemory(to:capacity:)`, `assumingMemoryBound(to:)`,
>     and `withMemoryRebound(to:capacity:)`. (SE-0107)

In your case, you may need to write something like this:

```
let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(to: &zeroAddress) {
    $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {zeroSockAddress in
        SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, zeroSockAddress)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18):

Replace

```
let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(to: &zeroAddress) {
  SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, UnsafePointer($0))
}
```

with

```
guard let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(to: &zeroAddress, {

        $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {

            SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, $0)

        }

    }) else {

        return false
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Swift 3 updated the syntax,exact solution is,

```
guard let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(to: &zeroAddress, {
    $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {
        zeroSockAddress in SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, zeroSockAddress)} 
} ) else { 
    return false 
}
```