# Check internet connection (iOS 10)

Tags: swift3, ios10, internet-connection

For iOS 9 I was using Reachability public class to check wether the device is connected to the internet or not. I converted my Swift 2 code to Swift 3, and the Reachability doesn't work anymore. Can someone tell me how to check the internet connection on iOS 10? Thanks!
Here's the code snippet:

```
open class Reachability {
    class func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool {
        var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in()
        zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: zeroAddress))
        zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)
        let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(to: &zeroAddress) {
            SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, UnsafePointer($0))
        }
        var flags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags()
        if !SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability!, &flags) {
            return false
        }
        let isReachable = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsReachable)) != 0
        let needsConnection = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired)) != 0
        return (isReachable && !needsConnection)
    }
}
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39046377/swift-3-unsafepointer0-no-longer-compile-in-xcode-8-beta-6

Comment: Please note that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25623272/how-to-use-scnetworkreachability-in-swift/25623647#25623647 has been updated for Swift 3.

Comment: I think this will help you with your Q:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/39783037/4301118

Comment: See alamofire answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/46562290/7576100

Answer (score 112, accepted):

```
import Foundation
import SystemConfiguration

func isInternetAvailable() -> Bool
    {
        var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in()
        zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: zeroAddress))
        zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

        let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(to: &zeroAddress) {
            $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {zeroSockAddress in
                SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, zeroSockAddress)
            }
        }

        var flags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags()
        if !SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability!, &flags) {
            return false
        }
        let isReachable = flags.contains(.reachable)
        let needsConnection = flags.contains(.connectionRequired)
        return (isReachable && !needsConnection)
    }
```

This works in iOS 10

Comment: this answer is good but not enough. if you will use this function, you must import SystemConfiguration

Comment: If you are connected to a wi-fi but not able to connect to the internet (open a google page) still it returns true for reachable. It's wrong.

Comment: This returns "true" when connected to the WiFi without the Internet, which is a problem for my case.

Comment: @PavleMijatovic so what is the solution to this problem ( returns "true" when connected to the WiFi without the Internet)? If you found out, please let me know as well.

Comment: @Tejas, here is how I implemented inside my code, I just pinged a site if I am on WiFi. You have down below my implementation.

Comment: @PavleMijatovic : Ok, Thank You! :)

Comment: But Apple says that Reachability API MUST only be used for diagnostic purposes. Proactive network check using Reachability is ill advised. Instead Apple wants you to handle it through exception Handling mechanism.

Answer (score 63):

**SWIFT 3.0**:
Here's very simple way to do it:

```
import SystemConfiguration


protocol Utilities {
}

extension NSObject:Utilities{


    enum ReachabilityStatus {
        case notReachable
        case reachableViaWWAN
        case reachableViaWiFi
    }

    var currentReachabilityStatus: ReachabilityStatus {

        var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in()
        zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout<sockaddr_in>.size)
        zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

        guard let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(to: &zeroAddress, {
            $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {
                SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, $0)
            }
        }) else {
            return .notReachable
        }

        var flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = []
        if !SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability, &flags) {
            return .notReachable
        }

        if flags.contains(.reachable) == false {
            // The target host is not reachable.
            return .notReachable
        }
        else if flags.contains(.isWWAN) == true {
            // WWAN connections are OK if the calling application is using the CFNetwork APIs.
            return .reachableViaWWAN
        }
        else if flags.contains(.connectionRequired) == false {
            // If the target host is reachable and no connection is required then we'll assume that you're on Wi-Fi...
            return .reachableViaWiFi
        }
        else if (flags.contains(.connectionOnDemand) == true || flags.contains(.connectionOnTraffic) == true) && flags.contains(.interventionRequired) == false {
            // The connection is on-demand (or on-traffic) if the calling application is using the CFSocketStream or higher APIs and no [user] intervention is needed
            return .reachableViaWiFi
        } 
        else {
            return .notReachable
        }
    }

}
```

and then simply you can use it anywhere in your project for example:

```
  func viewDidLoad(){
      print(currentReachabilityStatus != .notReachable) //true connected
    }
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me in swift3.

Comment: This one is the best solution. Very Swifty too.

Comment: If you are connected to a wi-fi but not able to connect to the internet (open a google page) still it returns true for reachable. It's wrong.

Comment: Great solution! Thanks.

Comment: I wish I could give this more than one upvote!  Should be the accepted solution.

Comment: I don't normally comment on here, but this solution blew me out of the water! Absolutely perfect!

Comment: can we also check for mobile cellular data?? So, that user can choose to use WiFi or, cellular data within the app.

Comment: This returns "true" when connected to the WiFi without the Internet, which is a problem for my case.

Comment: This code fails to work when wifi is connected but internet is not available

Comment: How can I add a functionality for callback when the reachability status changes?

Comment: Type 'SCNNetworkReachabilityFlags' has no member 'isWWAN'. Red error. Could someone help me out? Seems to be updated in Swift 4.0?!

Answer (score 11):

Try this, it works for me 
first **import** the **SystemConfiguration** to your class.

```
import SystemConfiguration
```

And now implement bellow function.

```
func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool {

    var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in(sin_len: 0, sin_family: 0, sin_port: 0, sin_addr: in_addr(s_addr: 0), sin_zero: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
    zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: zeroAddress))
    zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)
    let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(to: &zeroAddress) {
        $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {zeroSockAddress in
            SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, zeroSockAddress)
        }
    }

    var flags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags()
    if !SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability!, &flags) {
        return false
    }
    let isReachable = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsReachable)) != 0
    let needsConnection = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired)) != 0

    return (isReachable && !needsConnection)

}
```

Comment: It appears there is a flaw in this code.  Checking for flags with == doesn't work properly.

Comment: dear  @ryantxr this code works properly for me, i hope u are using swift 3.0, and if you find the better solution for this, then you can put it here, please dont downmark the answer

Comment: You can fix it with `flags.contains(.reachable)` and `flags.contains(.connectionRequired)`.
Yes I am using Swift 3.

Comment: If you are connected to a wi-fi but not able to connect to the internet (open a google page) still it returns true for reachable. It's wrong.

Comment: This code is giving me a problem. Its works properly for WiFi but if I connect using cellular data and check, it says no internet even though the internet is available.

Comment: @ArildoJunior Make a response data check. Like if the response data is nil, then you're offline.

Answer (score 8):

step 1 : create a swift file in your project. i created "ConnectionCheck.swift"

step 2 : add this code in your "ConnectionCheck.swift" file and "import SystemConfiguration" file to your "ConnectionCheck.swift" and "ViewController.swift"

```
import Foundation
import SystemConfiguration
public class ConnectionCheck {

class func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool {

    var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in()
    zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout<sockaddr_in>.size)
    zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

    guard let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(to: &zeroAddress, {
        $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {
            SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, $0)
        }
    }) else {
        return false
    }

    var flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = []
    if !SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability, &flags) {
        return false
    }

    let isReachable = flags.contains(.reachable)
    let needsConnection = flags.contains(.connectionRequired)

    return (isReachable && !needsConnection)
}
```

}

step 3 : Now in "ViewController.swift" use this code to check Network Reachability

```
if ConnectionCheck.isConnectedToNetwork() {
        print("Connected")
    }
    else{
        print("disConnected")
    }
```

Comment: If I submit my app to apple, do I need to change any code in order to pass apple verification？

Comment: @LOLXDXPLOL yes, we can see... But SO work with multiple answer so others can see different version and maybe, just maybe, a better solution shows up... I'm trying to remain polite.

Comment: @ByronCoetsee sorry, I didn’t want to sound impolite, I just didn’t think of it that way. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This code would be helpful for you. it worked for me in Swift 4 and Xcode 9

Go to https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift/tree/master/Reachability
and copy Reachability.swift file to your project

Vasil Nunev clearly explain this Reachability
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDZmz9IsB-8

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

   let reachability = Reachability();
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        reachability?.whenReachable = { _ in

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
            }
        }

        reachability?.whenUnreachable = { _ in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            }
        }
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(internetChanged), name: Notification.Name.reachabilityChanged , object: reachability)
        do{

            try reachability?.startNotifier()
        }catch{
            print("Could not start notifier:\(error)")
        }

    }

    @objc func internetChanged(note:Notification)  {
        let reachability  = note.object as! Reachability

        if reachability.connection != .none {

            if reachability.connection == .wifi{
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.view.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.3411764801, green: 0.6235294342, blue: 0.1686274558, alpha: 1)
                }
            }else if reachability.connection == .cellular{
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.view.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.3647058904, green: 0.06666667014, blue: 0.9686274529, alpha: 1)
                }
            }
        }else{
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.view.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.7450980544, green: 0.1568627506, blue: 0.07450980693, alpha: 1)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I’ve had a working answer a long time ago

Comment: Does this method work for cellular data as well as wifi? And does it distinguish between simply being connected to wifi and being connect to wifi *with* internet connection?

Comment: This code is not working for me. I dont know what am I doing wrong. It return true and then false when you get in network.

Answer (score 3):

Here is Swift 3 solution via callback function, `isConnectedToNetwork()` is taken from the solution by Yasin Ugurlu from above.

```
class func isInternetAvailable(webSiteToPing: String?, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {

    // 1. Check the WiFi Connection
    guard isConnectedToNetwork() else {
      completionHandler(false)
      return
    }

    // 2. Check the Internet Connection
    var webAddress = "https://www.google.com" // Default Web Site
    if let _ = webSiteToPing {
      webAddress = webSiteToPing!
    }

    guard let url = URL(string: webAddress) else {
      completionHandler(false)
      print("could not create url from: \(webAddress)")
      return
    }

    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
      if error != nil || response == nil {
        completionHandler(false)
      } else {
        completionHandler(true)
      }
    })

    task.resume()
  }
```

Comment: your answer looks good and your comment above about the accepted answer connecting to wifi but no internet is correct. How do you call your function and use it inside a view controller? Please show an example

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4 / Xcode 10:**

I would combine two functions ( with a bit changes) are taken from the solutions by @Pavle Mijatovic and @Krutagn Patel (with thanks) to answer @Lance Samaria question. :)

I almost checked all the possibilities. (the code can be enhanced, but it works fine)

have a class as below:

```
import Foundation
import SystemConfiguration

public class ConnectionCheck {

    class func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool {

        var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in()
        zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout<sockaddr_in>.size)
        zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

        guard let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(to: &zeroAddress, {
            $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {
                SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, $0)
            }
        }) else {
            return false
        }

        var flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = []
        if !SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability, &flags) {
            return false
        }

        let isReachable = flags.contains(.reachable)
        let needsConnection = flags.contains(.connectionRequired)

        return (isReachable && !needsConnection)
    }


    class func isInternetAvailable(webSiteToPing: String?, completionHandler: @escaping (_ b: Bool) -> Void) {

        // 1. Check the WiFi Connection
        guard isConnectedToNetwork() else {
            completionHandler(false)
            return
        }

        // 2. Check the Internet Connection
        var webAddress = "https://www.google.com" // Default Web Site
        if let _ = webSiteToPing {
            webAddress = webSiteToPing!
        }

        guard let url = URL(string: webAddress) else {
            completionHandler(false)
            print("could not create url from: \(webAddress)")
            return
        }

        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil || response == nil {
                completionHandler(false)
            } else {
                completionHandler(true)
            }
        })

        task.resume()
    }
}
```

use the below code where you need to check the Internet connection: for example, in *appDelegate -> applicationDidBecomeActive* function.

explanation: whenever completionHandler function (above) is called, the result (true or false) is passed to the below code as `b`. so if b is true you have the Internet connection.

```
let web : String? = "https://www.google.com"
ConnectionCheck.isInternetAvailable(webSiteToPing: web) { (b)  in
 print(b)
if b {
print("connected") // or do something here
    } else {
print("disconnected") // or do something here
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use in swift 3

```
import SystemConfiguration

class Connection {

    class func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool {

        var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in(sin_len: 0, sin_family: 0, sin_port: 0, sin_addr: in_addr(s_addr: 0), sin_zero: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
        zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(sizeofValue(zeroAddress))
        zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

        let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(&zeroAddress) {
            SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(kCFAllocatorDefault, UnsafePointer($0))
        }

        var flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags(rawValue: 0)
        if SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability!, &flags) == false {
            return false
        }

        let isReachable = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsReachable)) != 0
        let needsConnection = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired)) != 0

        return isReachable && !needsConnection

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a new Swift file within your project, name it “Reachability.swift”.

2) Cut & paste the following code into it to create your class.

```
import Foundation
import SystemConfiguration

public class Reachability {

class func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool {

    var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in(sin_len: 0, sin_family: 0, sin_port: 0, sin_addr: in_addr(s_addr: 0), sin_zero: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
    zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(sizeofValue(zeroAddress))
    zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

    let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(&zeroAddress) {
        SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(kCFAllocatorDefault, UnsafePointer($0))
    }

    var flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags(rawValue: 0)
    if SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability!, &flags) == false {
        return false
    }

    let isReachable = flags == .Reachable
    let needsConnection = flags == .ConnectionRequired

    return isReachable && !needsConnection

     }
}
```

3) You can check internet connection anywhere in your project using this code:

```
 if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true {
println("Internet connection OK")
} else {
println("Internet connection FAILED")
}
```

4)If the user is not connected to the internet, you may want to show them an alert dialog to notify them.

```
if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true {
println("Internet connection OK")
} else {
println("Internet connection FAILED")
var alert = UIAlertView(title: "No Internet Connection", message: "Make sure your 
 device is connected to the internet.", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
alert.show()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4/Xcode 9+ (make Reachability.swift file):

```
public class Reachability {

    class func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool {

        var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in(sin_len: 0, sin_family: 0, sin_port: 0, sin_addr: in_addr(s_addr: 0), sin_zero: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
        zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: zeroAddress))
        zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

        let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(to: &zeroAddress) {
            $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {zeroSockAddress in
                SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, zeroSockAddress)
            }
        }

        var flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags(rawValue: 0)
        if SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability!, &flags) == false {
            return false
        }

        // Working for Cellular and WIFI
        let isReachable = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsReachable)) != 0
        let needsConnection = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired)) != 0
        let ret = (isReachable && !needsConnection)

        return ret

    }
}
```

usage:

```
if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() {
// connected, do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a Swift file within your project, name it: Reachability.swift".
   then paste below code in this Reachability.swift file:-

   ```
   import Foundation

   import SystemConfiguration

   public class Reachability {

       class func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool {

           var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in(sin_len: 0, sin_family: 0, sin_port: 0, sin_addr: in_addr(s_addr: 0), sin_zero: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
           zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(sizeofValue(zeroAddress))
           zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

           let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(&zeroAddress) {
               SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(kCFAllocatorDefault, UnsafePointer($0))
           }

           var flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags(rawValue: 0)
           if SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability!, &flags) == false {
               return false
           }

           let isReachable = flags == .Reachable
           let needsConnection = flags == .ConnectionRequired

           return isReachable && !needsConnection

       }
   }
   ```

Then you can check the internet anywhere in the project using below code

```
  if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true {
        println("Internet connection OK")
    } else {
        println("Internet connection FAILED")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for Swift 4.0. Not a big fan o IUO rather use a guard

```
 func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool {
    var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in()
    zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: zeroAddress))
    zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

    guard let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(to: &zeroAddress, {
        $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {
            SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, $0)
        }
    }) else {
        return false
    }

    var flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags(rawValue: 0)
    if SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability, &flags) == false {
        return false
    }

    let isReachable = flags == .reachable
    let needsConnection = flags == .connectionRequired
    return isReachable && !needsConnection
}
```