# Swift 3 - Alamofire request - Save request to disk

Tags: swift, serialization, swift3, request, alamofire

I am asking this question because I didn't found any resources on this issue, and therefore I can't complete my project on this.

I have this basic alamofire post request:

```
let request = Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/post", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
```

If I am not connected to the Internet, I want to save this request and then perform it again when the internet is connected.

Any ideas on how to start on this issue? Any suggestion will be very much appreciated.

Comment: I may be missing something, but surely all you need to do is manage a text file in JSON format that stores the parameters for any outstanding requests that you can't carry out immediately. When connectivity is restored, read in the request parameters from the file to create the requests, and delete the entries that successfully execute.

Comment: and how should i save a swift "variable" to a text file?

Comment: Take a look at the Apple docs on JSONSerialization: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonserialization. You essentially want to convert the JSON to a Data object that you can then write to file and read back in later. But also take a look at the posted answer that has crossed with my comment.

Answer (score 0):

1. With the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40148883/2299040) determine if there is working
   internet connection or not.
2. case when there is no internet connection
   Save your post parameters in your user default or [file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24098149/2299040)
3. Follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27310748/2299040) to get to know when iphone is again
   connected to  internet.
4. with the help of answer linked in step 2 read your parameters from
   file and make the post request