# How to migrate array.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer from swift 2 to swift 3?

Tags: swift, swift3, swift2

I want to use code from [this link](https://github.com/SwiftGL/Image/blob/master/Sources/Image.swift)
which is in swif 2

```
public protocol SGLImageType {
    typealias Element
    var width:Int {get}
    var height:Int {get}
    var channels:Int {get}
    var rowsize:Int {get}
    
    func withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer(
        @noescape body: (UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Element>) throws -> Void
    ) rethrows
}
```

a class implemented above protocol:

```
final public class SGLImageRGBA8 : SGLImageType { ... public func withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer(@noescape body: (UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<UInt8>) throws -> Void) rethrows {
    try array.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer(){
        // This is unsafe reinterpret cast. Be careful here.
        let st = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>($0.baseAddress)
        try body(UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<UInt8>(start: st, count: $0.count*channels))
    }
}
```

in swift 3, the line `let st = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>($0.baseAddress)` throws this error:

> 'init' is unavailable: use 'withMemoryRebound(to:capacity:_)' to
> temporarily view memory as another layout-compatible type

how to resolve this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift 3 UnsafePointer($0) no longer compile in Xcode 8 beta 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39046377/swift-3-unsafepointer0-no-longer-compile-in-xcode-8-beta-6)

Comment: @kennytm its not duplicate of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert the `UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<UInt8>` to a `UnsafeMutableRawBufferPointer`, bind that to `UInt8` and create an `UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<UInt8>` from that (using dummy values here for all the properties):

```
final public class SGLImageRGBA8 : SGLImageType {
    public var width: Int = 640
    public var height: Int = 480
    public var channels: Int = 4
    public var rowsize: Int = 80
    public var array:[(r:UInt8,g:UInt8,b:UInt8,a:UInt8)] =
        [(r:UInt8(1), g:UInt8(2), b:UInt8(3), a:UInt8(4))]

    public func withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer(body: @escaping (UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<UInt8>) throws -> Void) rethrows {
        try array.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer(){ bp in
            let rbp = UnsafeMutableRawBufferPointer(bp)
            let p = rbp.baseAddress!.bindMemory(to: UInt8.self, capacity: rbp.count)
            try body(UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(start: p, count: rbp.count))
        }
    }
}

SGLImageRGBA8().withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { (p: UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<UInt8>) in
    print(p, p.count)
    p.forEach { print($0) }
}
```

prints

```
UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(start: 0x000000010300e100, count: 4) 4
1, 2, 3, 4
```

See [UnsafeRawPointer Migration](https://swift.org/migration-guide/se-0107-migrate.html) and [SE-0107](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0107-unsaferawpointer.md) for more information.