# How to Check for internet connection availability in Swift 3.0?

Tags: swift3

I am getting lot of the error when i try to use the code of previous version swift.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use SCNetworkReachability in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25623272/how-to-use-scnetworkreachability-in-swift)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25623647/1187415 has been updated for Swift 3 some time ago ...

Comment: Hi Martin R.. whatever link have you share, is not working in swift 3.0

Comment: How is it "not working"? Did you check the Swift 3 update in http://stackoverflow.com/a/25623647/1187415?

Comment: Sorry Martin R ... its working fine ( i forgot to import the SystemConfiguration)...Thanks a lot

Comment: No problem, you are welcome!