# How to convert following code in swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm trying to convert this code into Swift, but I don't know how to achieve it:

```
    struct sockaddr_in6 zeroAddress;
    bzero(&zeroAddress, sizeof(zeroAddress));
    zeroAddress.sin6_len = sizeof(zeroAddress);
    zeroAddress.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
    return [self reachabilityWithAddress: &zeroAddress];
```

Thank you.

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/25623647/1187415: That uses a `sockaddr_in` (IPv4 socket), but it should be easy to change the code for `sockaddr_in6` (IPv6 socket).

Comment: @MartinR i have trying it but how i write this line   bzero(&zeroAddress, sizeof(zeroAddress));  in swift

Comment: You don't: Just `let zeroAddress = sockaddr_in6()`, that already zero-initializes the struct (as shown and explained in the answer that I linked to).

Comment: @MartinR i have convert this code  var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in()
    zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout<sockaddr_in>.size)
    zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)     to  var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in6()
        zeroAddress.sin6_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout<sockaddr_in6>.size)
        zeroAddress.sin6_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET6) but always get true

Comment: It is impossible to read that code in a comment. Please edit your question and include the code that you tried.

Comment: Have you tried swiftify. @Hiren

Comment: yes i have tried but its not work. @KAR