# Check For Internet Connectivity In Swift

Tags: swift3, reachability

I am using Swift 3 and Xcode 8. All the other scripts and stuff online to do this all raise a lot of errors. How would I in a simple way make the app check for an Internet connection when it was launched and if it had one to continue and if it doesn't have a connection to show the user a popup saying so?

I am open to any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to check for internet connectivity is to use the iOS reachability api.

It's available in the SystemConfiguration module.

[Objective-C Reachability Example](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)

A good example of using SCNetworkReachability in swift is found in the stack overflow answer:

[SCNetworkReachability in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25623272/how-to-use-scnetworkreachability-in-swift)

I hope this helps! Have a nice day!