# How to use Reachability in Network Extension, it never callback

Tags: ios, objective-c

I use Reachability demo to check wifi connect, it work fine, now, i want use it in a network extension

Set callback is ok, but it nerver callback even network connect is change.

```
SCNetworkReachabilityContext context = {0, (__bridge void *)(self), NULL, NULL, NULL};
if (SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback(_reachabilityRef, ReachabilityCallback, &context)) // return YES {
    if (SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop(_reachabilityRef, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode)) { //return YES
    //...
    }
}
```

never call this:

```
static void ReachabilityCallback(SCNetworkReachabilityRef target, SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags, void* info){
    //...
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use SCNetworkReachability in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25623272/how-to-use-scnetworkreachability-in-swift)

Comment: Thanks, i read this question, but want my problem is use this code in  network extension

Comment: Solve the problem by set callback in main thread

Comment: You can answer, your own question. Please share solution here by posting an answer, so It would be helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

Solve the problem by set callback in main thread，because if the thread is dead，it will never call back.