# iOS 11 network change AVPlayer audio streaming bug

Tags: avplayer, audio-streaming, ios11, swift4, live-streaming

Revised Question (based on the now documented AVPlayer bug):

I found a workaround using this code as a base: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25623647/6697755

I found isWWAN flag can be used to check network type

```
var flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = []
let isCellular = flags.contains(.isWWAN)
```

It seems to be a pretty reliable check.
So I can now derive a network type change and reboot the player.

...only took me about 80 hours to find this workaround ;|

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem when I updated to iOS 11. I filed a bug at Apple's Bug Reporter and Open Radar - [rdar://35270862](https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4989228005982208)

Comment: i duplicated your radar a few days ago! hope they fix the issue soon.

Answer (score 1):

I've edited my question with a workaround to resume playback after leaving or entering wifi.

If anyone has any info on how to fix this or exactly why this issue occurred in iOS11 please let us know.