# How to set delegate for Alamofire respone

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to `IOS`. And I am using `Alamofire` for making network request. I have been very much successful in doing following...

1. Making request with parameters
2. Showing activity indicator
3. Getting Response and hiding activity indicator
4. Parsing response into modal

I have good concept of OOP. and I have good experience of working in android. In android I use to make a centralized class for services, and calls it from activities, and then I pass the result using callbacks.

In this way the it is more compact and avoids me in writing same code again and again. I search on it, and found that delegate are the same thing as Callbacks/Interfaces in java/android.

**My Question:**

> Can Any one tell me how to make a `Alamofire` code in one class and how
>   to call that from other **View controllers** with different number and
>   type of parameters. and with different type of results to send back
>   into related View controller? is it possible and how using **swift**??

Comment: Use **Blocks** instead.

Comment: @iPeter what do you mean by Blocks?

Comment: **Callback** methods.

Comment: you need to learn about closure.

Comment: As you have decided to adopt a better approach. I would like to suggest you to check `PromiseKit`. It has already embedded the above part that you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @UmairAfzal please gimme example

Comment: @Androidteem: Please check my answer below. I have shown you an example of closure.

Comment: @iPeter yes just wait I am looking at it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create one swift file with WebServicesCall or your preferred name and use following code. here I am using `SwiftyJSON` and `Alamofire`.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

struct WebService {
static func requestService(url: URL, method: HTTPMethod, parameters: Parameters, headers: HTTPHeaders? = nil, showLoaderFlag: Bool, viewController: UIViewController, completion: @escaping (_ success: JSON) -> Void) {
        /* check for internet connection */
        if(Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork()) {
            /* Show Loader here */

            print("Web Service - \(url)")
            print("Header - \(String(describing: headers))")
            print("Parameters - \(parameters)")

            /* Request configure */
            AlmofireService.Manager.request(url, method: method, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: header) .responseJSON { response in
                print("Response - \(response)")

                switch response.result {
                case .success(_):
                    /* Hide loader here */

                    let json = JSON(response.result.value!)

                    completion(json)

                case .failure(_):
                    print("Request failed with error: \(response.result.error ?? "" as! Error)")

                    if response.result.error?._code == NSURLErrorTimedOut {
                        //TODO: show response time out alert or message here
                    } else {
                        //TODO: show response failure alert or message here
                    }

                    /* Hide loader here */

                    completion(JSON.null)
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("No internet connection")

            //TODO: show no internet connection alert or message here

            let json: JSON = ["status": "nointernet",
                          "code": 503]
            completion(json)
        }
    }
    }
```

And then call as following when your need

```
func callWebService() {
        let parameters: [String: Any] = ["key": "value"] //for post request
        let headers: [String: String] = ["key": "value"]
        let url = //your url here

        WebService.requestService(url: url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, headers: headers, showLoaderFlag: true, viewController: self, completion: { response in

            guard response["code"].int != 503 else {
                print("No internet connection")
                return
            }

            guard response != .null else {
                return
            }

            /* Handle your success response here */

        })
    }
```

Comment: I have one question. What if the response is not nil and the response contains a reason able error message (where success == false)

Comment: on `print("Request failed with error: \(response.result.error ?? "" as! Error)")` this line you will get error messge

Comment: Thats fine but it must also be delegated to main view controller

Comment: Now check my updated code for no internet connection you can modified like this to for other error messages

Comment: I am trying your answer but getting this error 
Cannot load underlying module for 'SwiftyJSON'

Comment: If this ans was helpful to you then please up vote so it can help other

Comment: I am trying this, then I will furthur comment on it

Comment: well adding point it is good to use default case for /* Hide loader here */

Comment: there is an error Use of unresolved identifier 'Reachability'

Comment: there are alot of errors Type 'Reachability' has no member 'isConnectedToNetwork'

Comment: For `Reachability` https://stackoverflow.com/a/25623647/5523205 and use swift 3/4 updated code

Comment: and there is another error Use of unresolved identifier 'json' on line guard json["code"].int != 503 else {
                print("No internet connection")
                return
            }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173552/discussion-between-shahrukh-and-android-teem).

Answer (score 1):

Create a NSObject class and and create a class level function inside it. and call it from any other class

```
import Alamofire

class Network: NSObject {

class func API_PostData(_ strURL: String, parameter Params: NSDictionary, successWithStatus1Closure: @escaping (AnyObject?) -> (), successWithStatus0Closure: @escaping (AnyObject?) -> (), failurClosure: @escaping (String?)-> ())
    {

        let Param: [String: Any] = Params.mutableCopy() as! [String : Any]


        let complite_url = BASE_URL+strURL


        if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork(){



            Alamofire.request(complite_url, method: .post, parameters: Param ,encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON {
                response in
                if(response.result.error != nil)
                {
                    let error = response.result.error
                    if (error?.localizedDescription == "The request timed out."){
                        failurClosure("The request timed out.");
                        return
                    }
                    if (error?.localizedDescription == "Could not connect to the server."){
                        failurClosure("Could not connect to the server.");
                        return
                    }
                    if (error?.localizedDescription == "The network connection was lost."){
                        failurClosure("The network connection was lost.");
                        return
                    }
                }
                let dictResponse = response.result.value as? NSDictionary

                print("Response",response)

                if dictResponse is Dictionary<AnyHashable,Any> {
                    print("Yes, it's a Dictionary")
                }
                else{
                    print("No, it's a not a Dictionary")
                    failurClosure("Active internet connection required")
                    return
                }

                let isSuccess = dictResponse!["success"] as! Int

                if isSuccess == 1
                {
                    successWithStatus1Closure(dictResponse)
                }else{
                    successWithStatus0Closure(dictResponse)
                }

            }
        }else {

            print("Active internet connection required");
            failurClosure("Active internet connection required")
            return
        }

    }
    }
```

and use it like

```
Network.API_PostData
```

and xCode will autocompleted the method

Uses Example in your view controller create a method

```
func callApi(){
    let para = ["user_id" : USER_ID_STR,
                "page" : String(page),
                "item_per_page" : "15"
        ] as NSDictionary
    SVProgressHUD.show()
    GlobalClass.API_PostData("notifications/activities", parameter: para, successWithStatus1Closure: { (response) in

        print("response \(response)")
        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
    }, successWithStatus0Closure:{ (response) in
        print("response \(response)")
        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
    }, failurClosure: { (error) in
        print("error \(error ?? "ddd")")
        GlobalClass.showAlert(alertTitle: "", alertMsg: error!, view: self)
        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
    })
}
```

and call it like

```
callApi()
```

Comment: how to use it and how to send back data to main view  controller in 3 case , success, fail and request time out exception ???

Comment: You can see the SuccessClosure and FailiureClosure . these are escaping closure return to the main class . lemmi give you a example

Comment: i have add the example in answer

Comment: I understand but there is a question

Comment: Okkee ask what question you have

Comment: what is difference between   successWithStatus1Closure(dictResponse) and successWithStatus0Closure(dictResponse)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173536/discussion-between-android-teem-and-ajay-saini).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your requirement by writing **Callback** methods or **Closures**. For example:

```
func yourMethodName(completion:@escaping (YourModelClass) -> Void,onError:@escaping (Error) -> Void) {
    let dataRequest = RequestObject()
    dataRequest.apiURL = YourApiURl
    dataRequest.headers = DesiredHeaders
    dataRequest.requestType = RequestType

    //This will be your method for the webservice call, whenever you get success or error, return a callback to the calling class via completion.
    NetworkManager.getDataFor(Request: dataRequest, success: {response in
        //print(response.responseObject!)
        let model = YourModelClass.init(WithDictionary: response.responseObject as? [String : Any])
        completion(model)
    }, failure: {error in
        onError(error)
  })
}
```

Hope this helps. 
For any query feel free to leave a comment.

Comment: So, he has to copy this method at n number of places for n number of API's?

Comment: @Kamran: To create different models for different responses, he have to write different methods right?

Comment: No, one method can do it.

Comment: How can you create different models in one method?

Comment: By conforming models to `Decodable` and then having a `generic method` that takes the `model type` and return the `decoded object`.

Comment: I think Kamran is right. How about returning the whole response to calling view controller., and calling controller manage the response in its on way

Comment: Thats your choice what you want in your calling controller, but this way using a closure you can get the callback.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**Swift**

In WebService Class : post the notification

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "yourNotificationName"), object: nil)
```

In your class where you want to receive the response : register first for the notification, and write a method to handle it.
You give the corresponding selector to the method.
// view did load

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(yourClass.handleUpdatedData), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "yourNotificatioName"), object: nil)

-(void)handleUpdatedData:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"recieved");
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

**Objective C...**

In WebService Class : post the notification

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DataUpdated"
                                                        object:self];
```

In your class where you want to receive the response : register first for the notification, and write a method to handle it.
You give the corresponding selector to the method.
// view did load

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(handleUpdatedData:)
                                             name:@"DataUpdated"
                                           object:nil];

-(void)handleUpdatedData:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"recieved");
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Notification should not be used here.

Comment: Notifications are bad here.

Comment: It can be done using `NotificationCenter` but it is a terrible idea to achieve using this way. Closures with tuples or delegate is far better solutions than this.